Pydantic - Migrate from v1 to v2 - @validator to @field_validator
As pydantic got upgraded from v1 to v2, I need to migrate the following piece of code from @validator to @field_validator. I'm facing issues to understand how can I validate more than one field.

how can always behaviour be replicated in v2. In v2 this is not supported. Found validate_default=True in documentation but couldn't find a proper example to showcase the use.
how to access field.name keyword. This is used to access all the arguments present in @validator decorator.

I understand that for values we can use info: ValidationInfo.
Does anyone know how could the piece of code be migrated to v2.
Thanks
class Task(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str]
    pwd: Optional[str]
    depends_on: Optional[Union[str, List[str]]] = []
    features: Optional[Dict] = {}

    @validator("name", "pwd", "depends_on", "features", always=True)
        def validate_required_fields(cls, value, values, field):
            task_type = values.get("task_type")
            for task, fields in task_required.items():
                if task_type == task and field.name in fields:
                    if not value:
                        raise ValueError(f"{field} is mandatory for task type '{task_type}'")
            return value


The validate_default is an option in Field (docs).
As you correctly identified, ValidationInfo (docs) now has all the information about the fields and the already validated data.
A v2 validator could look like the following. Although you do not specify where task_type comes from (why is it not a permanent field?) and how task_required is defined.
from typing import Any, Literal
from pydantic import (
    BaseModel,
    field_validator,
    ValidationInfo,
    Field,
    ConfigDict,
)

task_required: dict[str, list[str]] = {
    "basic": [],
    "extra": ["depends_on"],
}


class Task(BaseModel):
    task_type: Literal["basic", "extra"] = Field(
        ...,
        description="Type of task",
    )
    name: str | None = Field(
        ...,
        description="Name of the task",
    )
    pwd: str | None = Field(
        ...,
        description="Working directory of the task",
    )
    depends_on: str | list[str] | None = Field(
        default_factory=list,
        description="Task dependencies",
        validate_default=True,
    )
    features: dict | None = Field(
        default_factory=dict,
        description="Task features",
        validate_default=True,
    )

    model_config = ConfigDict(extra="allow")

    @field_validator("name", "pwd", "depends_on", "features")
    @classmethod
    def validate_required_fields(cls, value: Any, info: ValidationInfo):
        task_type = info.data.get("task_type", "")

        if task_type not in task_required:
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid task type "{task_type}".')

        required_fields = task_required[task_type]
        if info.field_name in required_fields and not value:
            raise ValueError(
                f'Field "{info.field_name}" is required for task "{task_type}".'
            )

        return value


Task(task_type="extra", name="example", pwd=".")

#ValidationError: 1 validation error for Task
#depends_on
#  Value error, Field "depends_on" is required for task "extra". [type=value_error, input_value=[], input_type=list]
#    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/value_error


It seems that you actually have to define task_type in the model. Otherwise, it was not available under info.data.
